# How to install vscode extensions to all users?

Tags: visual-studio

when i install vscode extension, it is getting copied to c:\users.vscode\extensions.

How to make it available to all users in the machine.

Copyig to c:\programdata.vscode\extensions didn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [issue has been discussed](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/56614#issuecomment-697961001) on github.

Installing an extension and then moving the directory from the user profile to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions` (note: `Program Files`, not `Program Data`) is working fine as of September 2022.

*Addendum December 2023:*

On Linux, extensions may go into the `/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions` directory. It should be owned by root. It looks like there must be no `extensions.json` in that directory.

Some extensions (such as `ms-vscode.cpptools`) come with helper executables which must be executable. I did it like this (assuming there will never be an extension with a space in one of its paths):

```
chmod +x $(find /usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions -type f -exec file {} \; | grep -E 'ELF[^,]+executable' | cut -d: -f1)
```